# Freemarker print date in template

Tags: templates, datetime, freemarker, pojo, pretty-print

I am trying to print the current date when the template is activated. I have read that I have to pass a new Date() Java object to the template, but I don't know how to do that or where to put it in the code.

Does someone know how to pass a Java object to the template in this case?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 16):

Actually you don't have to pass a `new Date()` to your template, because placing a timestamp into a template's output is quite common and therefore FreeMarker provides a [special variable](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html) called `.now` which returns the current date and time. You can use it in your template like this:

```
Page generated: ${.now}
```

(FreeMarker also contains different built-ins for formatting dates: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html)

Update: Works only with the latest version of FreeMarker, [2.3.17](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_17.html).

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but I am getting this error: ParseException: Unknown built-in variable: now

Comment: The way I am doing it is with ${content.metaData.modificationDate?string.short}. The content.metaData.modificationDate gives me the last modification of that template which is pretty much what I need.

Comment: The special variable `.now` was introduced in version 2.3.17 (see http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_17.html), which was released about a week ago. If you cannot update you'll have to pass a the current date into the data model, e.g. as part of your root hashmap (see http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_createdatamodel.html and http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_merge.html for the details, if you don't already know those things).

Answer (score 6):

`${.now}` is the perfect answer. Just wanted to add few other ways to get direct values from date

```
#-- Predefined format names: -->

${openingTime?string.short}
${openingTime?string.medium}
${openingTime?string.long}
${openingTime?string.full}
${openingTime?string.xs} <#-- XSD xs:time -->
${openingTime?string.iso} <#-- ISO 8601 time -->

${.now?string.short}
${.now?string.medium}
${.now?string.long}
${.now?string.full}
${.now?string.xs} <#-- XSD xs:date -->
${.now?string.iso} <#-- ISO 8601 date -->

${.now?string.short}
${.now?string.medium}
${.now?string.long}
${.now?string.full}
${.now?string.medium_short} <#-- medium date, short time -->
${.now?string.xs} <#-- XSD xs:dateTime -->
${.now?string.iso} <#-- ISO 8601 combined date and time -->

<#-- Programmer-defined named format (@ + name): -->
${.now?string.@fileDate}

<#-- Advanced ISO 8601 and XSD formatting: -->
${.now?string.iso_m_u}
${.now?string.xs_ms_nz}

<#-- SimpleDateFormat patterns: -->
${.now?string["dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"]}
${.now?string["EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a '('zzz')'"]}
${.now?string["EEE, MMM d, ''yy"]}
${.now?string.yyyy} <#-- Same as ${.now?string["yyyy"]} -->
```

will output

```
01:45 PM
01:45:09 PM
01:45:09 PM PST
01:45:09 PM PST
13:45:09-08:00
13:45:09-08:00

2/20/07
Apr 20, 2007
April 20, 2007
Friday, April 20, 2007
2007-02-20-08:00
2007-02-20

2/20/07 01:45 PM
Feb 20, 2007 01:45:09 PM
February 20, 2007 01:45:09 PM PST
Friday, February 20, 2007 01:45:09 PM PST
Feb 8, 2003 9:24 PM
2007-02-20T13:45:09-08:00
2007-02-20T13:45:09-08:00

Apr/20/2007 13:45

2007-02-20T21:45Z
2007-02-20T13:45:09.000

08.04.2003 21:24
Tuesday, April 08, 2003, 09:24 PM (PDT)
Tue, Apr 8, '03
2003
```

[Source](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html)

Comment: Nice(actually not) copy-paste from official documentation. You could at least insert the [link](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html)

Comment: I took it from a tutorial, I usually put the link, not sure why I missed this one

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ObjectConstructor](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/utility/ObjectConstructor.html) API of Freemarker to create a calendar object and a formatter object, then combine the two to print the date:

```
<#-- Create constructor object -->
<#assign objectConstructor = "freemarker.template.utility.ObjectConstructor"?new()>

<#-- Call calendar constructor -->
<#assign clock = objectConstructor("java.util.GregorianCalendar")>

<#-- Call formatter constructor -->
<#assign mmddyy = objectConstructor("java.text.SimpleDateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy")>

<#-- Call getTime method to return the date in milliseconds-->
<#assign date = clock.getTime()>

<#-- Call format method to pretty print the date -->
<#assign now = mmddyy.format(date)>

<#-- Display date -->
${now}
```

> The `?new` built-in, as it was implemented, was a security hole. Now, it only allows you to instantiate a java object that implements the `freemarker.template.TemplateModel` interface. If you want the functionality of the ?new built-in as it existed in prior versions, make available an instance of the `freemarker.template.utility.ObjectConstructor` class to your template. For example:

```
myDataModel.put("objConstructor", new ObjectConstructor());
```

> and then in the template you can do this:

```
<#assign aList = objConstructor("java.util.ArrayList", 100)>)
```

**References**

- [Freemarker 2.3: Version History](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3.html)
- [Tag Developers Guide: Freemarker](http://struts.apache.org/docs/freemarker.html)
- [CRUD Operations using Servlet and FreeMarker Template Engine](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/07/crud-operations-using-servlet-and.html)

Comment: @mateen No problem. Hope it saved you time.